# gnuplot not showing correct scale on y axis for a circle

Tags: gnuplot, gnuplot-iostream

I am  modelling a graph problem using gnuplot

I am plotting a circle with gnuplot using the following command

```
set xtics 1
set ytics 1
plot 'circles.txt' with circle
```

my circles.txt contains the follwoing data

```
0 0 3
```

[image]

the upmost point on this circle(center at origin and radius of 3 ) should be (0,3) but it is shown as (0,2) in this graph

how can i rectify this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plotting with circles is intended for plotting the *points* as circles so they would be round regardless of axes scaling. As it is pointed in gnuplot documentation,

> The radius is always interpreted in the units of the plot's horizontal axis (x or x2). The scale on y and the aspect ratio of the plot are both ignored.

You can plot `with ellipses` instead; from documentation on `plot with ellipses`:

```
  2 columns: x y
  3 columns: x y major_diam
  4 columns: x y major_diam minor_diam
  5 columns: x y major_diam minor_diam angle
```

so you plot this as

```
plot 'circles.txt' using 1:2:($3*2):($3*2) with ellipses
```

(ellipses use diameter, so the size should be the third column twice)

Or `set object ellipse`:

```
 set object ellipse at 0, 0 size 6, 6
```